# TypeError: status.set is not a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, typeerror

I am getting the error above when I try to call a method from an other function.
Can someone help please!

**Method:**

```
     function Status() {

    var self = this;

    self.set = function(text) {
    var index;

    while (self.lblStatus.childNodes.length > 0) {
       self.lblStatus.removeChild(self.lblStatus.childNodes.item(0));
    }
    self.lblStatus.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    }
    }
```

and the calling in an other function is

```
    status.set(language.STATUS_CONTACTING_SERVER);
```

**The Error:**

> TypeError: status.set is not a function

can someone help please to find what's wrong with that!

Thank u

Comment: When you attempt to call `set` is the output of `console.log(status.set)` what you expect? Do you have the code in which you attempt to call this method?

Comment: the code in which I am trying to call the methode

function Identify() {
    var self = this;
 self.doIdentification = function(event) {
      
        logon.setEnabled(self.txtUsername, false);
        status.set(language.STATUS_CONTACTING_SERVER);

Comment: in console I just get that error TypeError: status.set is not a function

Comment: I can nearly guarantee that you didn't get `TypeError: status.set is not a function` with `console.log(status.set)`. At this point you need to use the debugger in your tool / browser of choice and make sure `status` is what you are expecting it to be

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not instantiating the class...

Where in your code do you have:

```
var status = new Status();
```

?

Also, from what you posted, there are missing properties and such (`lblStatus`).